# Why I got Not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, subquery

I would like to get the name and the language numbers if the country have more than 3 languages.But I don't know why I have 'not a single-group group function' error.

```
SELECT C.NAME,COUNT(L.LANGUAGE)
FROM WORLD.CITY C
INNER JOIN WORLD.COUNTRYLANGUAGE L ON C.COUNTRYCODE = L.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE C.COUNTRYCODE = (
    SELECT COUNTRYCODE
    FROM WORLD.COUNTRYLANGUAGE
    GROUP BY COUNTRYCODE HAVING COUNT(LANGUAGE) >3)
GROUP BY NAME;
```

```
DESC WORLD.CITY;

 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 NAME                      NOT NULL CHAR(35 CHAR)
 COUNTRYCODE                   NOT NULL CHAR(3 CHAR)
 DISTRICT                  NOT NULL CHAR(20 CHAR)
 POPULATION                NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
```

```
DESC WORLD.COUNTRYLANGUAGE;

 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COUNTRYCODE                   NOT NULL CHAR(3 CHAR)
 LANGUAGE                  NOT NULL CHAR(30 CHAR)
 ISOFFICIAL                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
 PERCENTAGE                NOT NULL FLOAT(126)
```

Comment: `ifofficial` as a varchar2(4000)? It takes 4000 chars to say "yes" or "no"?

Comment: I don't see how that query would generate that particular error.  Are you sure this is what you are running?  There are other issues with the query, but I don't see a problem with the aggregation.

Comment: i am sure this is the error i got. Is anyone can help? I need to do this using subquery. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite as:

```
SELECT C.NAME,COUNT(L.LANGUAGE)
FROM WORLD.CITY C
INNER JOIN WORLD.COUNTRYLANGUAGE L ON C.COUNTRYCODE = L.COUNTRYCODE
GROUP BY C.NAME
HAVING COUNT(L.LANGUAGE) > 3
```

Answer (score -1):

I Think you need **IN**, also when you do a group by all select elements have to be part of the group by clause

```
SELECT C.NAME,COUNT(L.LANGUAGE)
FROM WORLD.CITY C
INNER JOIN WORLD.COUNTRYLANGUAGE L ON C.COUNTRYCODE = L.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE C.COUNTRYCODE IN (
    SELECT COUNTRYCODE
    FROM WORLD.COUNTRYLANGUAGE
    GROUP BY COUNTRYCODE HAVING COUNT(LANGUAGE) >3)
GROUP BY NAME,COUNT(L.LANGUAGE);
```

Comment: Nope. You need to use `HAVING` not `WHERE`